# Pylint: not getting the "Redefining name" warning for _variable

Tags: python, pylint

Here are two almost identical functions. The only difference is the leading underscore in the variable name.

The code is incorrect without the `global` statement. The pylint's warning is this:

> W: 14, 8: Redefining name 'saved_args' from outer scope (line 9)
>   (redefined-outer-name)

However the first occurence of the same error was not detected. When the variable starts with an underscore, `pylint` remains silent. Why? Is it a bug or no?

```
_saved_args = []
def func1(*args):
    # global _saved_args

    if args != _saved_args:
        _saved_args = args
        # do something

saved_args = []
def func2(*args):
    # global saved_args

    if args != saved_args:
        saved_args = args
        # do something
```

Comment: what happens if you only have the first function and not the second one?

Comment: @snb No warning. This is how I discovered it. Pylint did not complain, but the program crashed.

Comment: So when you litterally just have _saved_args and func1 pylint doesn't complain? Strange since they both shadow variables out of scope, its possible that _name for scope follows a naming convention to ignore that part of linting, but I've never seen it in real life.